# What is the equivalent of Rail's Testing Routes in Django?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, testing

I was reading the [Rails testing doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) and it looks quite comprehensive in explaining the different type of tests.  I also noticed the section on [Testing Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-routes).  Does anyone know how I can do that in Django/Python?  I have a bunch of web sites with some common urls that I need to test.  Here's how it's done in Ruby:

```
def test_should_route_to_post 
  assert_routing '/posts/1', { :controller => "posts", :action => "show", :id => "1" }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django does have a fairly extensive library for testing Django web apps. The details of testing are a bit beyond the scope of this answer, but you can read the relevant docs about [testing Django applications](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#topics-testing) for more details. Particularly, I think you'll be interested in the sections on [making requests](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#making-requests) and [testing responses](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testing-responses), which allow you to make requests to URLs (for the purposes of testing), and test the responses. Django also has a `TestCase` subclass that includes [assertions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#assertions) specifically designed for use with HTTP requests and responses.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to test routes like Rails does, [Ryan Wilcox explains how to test routes directly](http://blog.wilcoxd.com/blog/2012/07/30/testing-urls-in-django-like-rails-route-testing/). To (briefly) encapsulate his answer, you can import the resolver and test what it resolves:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
>>> resolver = get_resolver(None)
>>> resolver.resolve('/some/path/')
ResolverMatch(func=...)
```

Note that failing to match throws an exception you will need to catch.

`get_resolver(None)` gets you the resolver for *all* the routes in your active settings.py; if you just want to test the routes from one app, you can do something like:

```
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import get_resolver
>>> import my_app
>>> resolver = get_resolver(my_app.urls)
```

(p.s. The above assumes you're in a django-happy interpreter, launched by `python manage.py shell`)